# Connect time-triggered Azure Function with Database using SQL Client

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, sqlclient, azure-function-async

I am connecting time-triggered Azure Function with SQL Server using SQL client but I am not getting any data.

Here is my code:

`local.settings.json`:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=; Initial Catalog=;User ID=;Password=;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Persist Security Info=True;"        
  }
}
```

`Function1.cs`:

```
public class Function1
{
   [FunctionName("Function1")]
   public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 45 14 * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
   {
     var sqlConnection = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DefaultConnection");
     using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnection))
     {
      conn.Open();
      var text = "SELECT * from UserMaster where UserId=1234";
      //This query has around 50 data in the database but still getting no data in it.
      
      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(text, conn))
      {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        {
          while (reader.Read())
          {
             log.LogInformation($"{reader.GetString(0)}{reader.GetString(1)} rows selected");
             Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
          }
        }
      }
     conn.Close();
    }
   log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
  }
}
```

I am not getting what is wrong with it. Please suggest

Comment: Do you get any exception? What happens during debug, especially the SqlConnection and executing the SqlCommand. Are they executed correctly? I assume that you removed the values for "DataSource", "UserID" etc. in your local.settings.json because you do not want to publish them on stackoverflow but normally you have values in there?

Comment: Hi @rekcul, I don't get any exception, it only shows that the table has no records. If I use the `ExecuteScalarAsync` instead of `ExecuteReaderAsync` the it works perfectly but the problem is that I want all the records instead of the single column of the 1st row. Also I purposely removed the values for "DataSource", "UserID" etc here in stackoverflow.

Comment: How is it going on? Did you got any break? Thanks for your response in advance : )

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `public override object this[string name] { get; }` instead. Here's my code and it worked well, you may compare it with yours.

```
 using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Function0602
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<List<tinyTest>> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            List<tinyTest> list = new List<tinyTest>();
            var str = "connect_string";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str))
            {
                conn.Open();
                var text = "select * from tinyTest;";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(text, conn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            tinyTest res = new tinyTest();
                            //SqlDataReader skd provide the method of reader["column_name"]
                            res.user_id = (string)reader["user_id"];
                            res.user_name = (string)reader["user_name"];
                            res.age = (int)reader["age"];
                            list.Add(res);
                        }
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            return list;
        }
    }

    public class tinyTest {
        public string user_id { get; set; }
        public string user_name { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: So the steps inside while loop are not executed as far as I understand?

Comment: I think you can check if reader has rows to make sure the query has got correct result. https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hoAe.png  If it's false, that means has no rows response.